# Как сформировать SQL запрос, чтобы одинаковые значения объединялись?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть три таблицы user, point_user, point
Запросом ниже вывожу имя, логин человека кол-во набранных очков и название за что дали очки.

```sql
SELECT user.login, user.name, point_user.pointsCount, point.pointKey
 FROM user, point_user, point
WHERE user.userId = point_user.userId 
  AND point_user.pointId = point.pointId 
ORDER BY user.login
```

В итоге таблица выдает такой результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы одинаковые значения объединялись, суммировались?

Comment: что нужно суммировать, можете разъяснить ?

Comment: полагаю, что очки, т.к. цифер больше нет)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

есть еще вариант такой

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT  user.login, user.name, point_user.pointsCount, point.pointKey
  FROM user, point_user, point
WHERE user.userId = point_user.userId 
   AND point_user.pointId = point.pointId 
ORDER BY user.login
```

DISTINCT - показывает только разные значения

---

Если нужно суммировать поле `point_user.pointsCount` тогда будет

```sql
SELECT user.login, user.name, sum(point_user.pointsCount) pointsCount, point.pointKey
 FROM user, point_user, point
WHERE user.userId = point_user.userId 
  AND point_user.pointId = point.pointId 
GROUP BY user.login, user.name, point.pointKey
ORDER BY user.login
```

---

**но было бы хорошо если сделать так**

```sql
SELECT user.login, user.name, sum(coalesce(point_user.pointsCount,0)) pointsCount, 
      point.pointKey
 FROM user
 LEFT JOIN point_user ON user.userId = point_user.userId 
 LEFT JOIN point ON point_user.pointId = point.pointId 
GROUP BY user.login, user.name, point.pointKey
ORDER BY user.login
```

Comment: Вы не вычисляете сумму. И к тому же, вы потеряете в представлении часть даных.

Comment: группировать по имени пользователя избыточно, т.к. логин должен быть уникальным иначе это не логин.

Comment: @ВиталийОбидейко может быть, но мы же не знаем как *Вадим Авлочинский* это сделал

Comment: в этом контексте возможно и справедливо.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогли!)

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно группировать по логину и по действию, за которое дали очки. А по полю очков брать сумму:

```sql
SELECT user.login, user.name, SUM(point_user.pointsCount) AS pointsCoun, point.pointKey
  FROM user, point_user, point
WHERE user.userId = point_user.userId 
  AND point_user.pointId = point.pointId 
GROUP BY user.login, point.pointKey
ORDER BY user.login
```

Comment: Когда отвечал, твоего ответа не было )

Comment: Начал писать, когда не было еще ответов. Да и к тому же ваш ответ не верный.))

Comment: @ВиталийОбидейко думаю `GROUP BY` будет перед `ORDER BY`